# QGIS: 'Incorrect parameter value for AGGREGATES' when using Aggregate in a Python-Processing-Script

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, qgs, aggregate

I am currently working on a QGIS-Python-Processing-Script that creates an automated street register for a printed city map as a CSV file.

In that context I want to give the user the option to choose which input data fields are included in the output csv file to make the plugin as versatile as possible.
To achieve this, I included the aggregate element in my UI.

```
self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterAggregate(
            "AggregateOutput", self.tr("Aggregate"), "StreetInput"
        )
    )
```

To access the aggregate elements value, I am using

```
aggregateOutput = self.parameterDefinition("AggregateOutput")
aggregateInputString = parameters["AggregateOutput"]
aggregatePythonString = aggregateOutput.valueAsPythonString(
        aggregateInputString, context
    )
```

I am pretty sure that this is quite a cumbersome way of getting the aggregate value, but right now it seems to work.

So when add my pythonString to the aggregate function like this

```
streetsAggregated = processing.run(
        "native:aggregate",
        {
            "AGGREGATES": aggregatePythonString,
            "GROUP_BY": "array("
            + streetNameField
            + ","
            + cityNameField
            + ")",
            "INPUT": filteredStreets,
            "OUTPUT": "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT",
        },
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )["OUTPUT"]
```

and run my plugin, I get the following error messages:

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for AGGREGATES
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for AGGREGATES
Execution failed after 0.30 seconds
```

However, if I print the value of my variable *aggregatePythonString*

```
[{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '\"gn\"','length': 40,'name': 'gn','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '\"str_schluessel\"','length': 5,'name': 'str_schluessel','precision': 0,'type': 10}]
```

to the Python console and copy and paste it into my code like this

```
streetsAggregated = processing.run(
        "native:aggregate",
        {
            "AGGREGATES": [
                {
                    "aggregate": "concatenate",
                    "delimiter": ",",
                    "input": '"gn"',
                    "length": 40,
                    "name": "gn",
                    "precision": 0,
                    "type": 10,
                },
                {
                    "aggregate": "concatenate",
                    "delimiter": ",",
                    "input": '"str_schluessel"',
                    "length": 5,
                    "name": "str_schluessel",
                    "precision": 0,
                    "type": 10,
                },
            ],
            "GROUP_BY": "array("
            + streetNameField
            + ","
            + cityNameField
            + ")",
            "INPUT": filteredStreets,
            "OUTPUT": "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT",
        },
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )["OUTPUT"]
```

the script runs perfectly fine. Is there any special magic when adding data to a processing algorithm via string? I also tried various different combinations of replacing single quotes with double quotes and other stuff, but that does not seem to cause the problem. It also works when the code is not pretty printed. Is there maybe something obvious that I am missing?